# The maximum of the modulus of complex valued function $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ on the circle of radius $a<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

My intuition is that the maximum is achieved when $z=a$. But I couldn't make a precise argument about it. Could anyone help me justify this?

Comment: So we want to show that $|f(z)|\leq  f(a)$ for all $z$ such that $|z|=a$

Comment: Geometric series expansion has positive coefficients so the value at the positive $a$ is greater than at any $ae^{i\theta}$ by taking absolute values and the triangle inequality; this is true for all Taylor series with positive (non negatives) coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+\ldots$$
For $|z|\leq a<1$, $$|f(z)|\leq1+|z|^2+|z|^3+\ldots\leq 1+a^2+a^3+\ldots$$
When $z=a$ we have
$$|f(a)|=|1+a+a^2+a^3+\ldots|=1+a+a^2+a^3+\ldots$$
So maximum is achieved at $z=a$.